# Unexpected result when using Sinon onCall method

Tags: sinon

I am experiencing an unexpected result :"should get data and has multiple recordSets" test case. My intention is to have the "stub.getRefundItems" method call return one set of results on the first call and a second set of results on the second call. The test works as expected if there are no other tests that use that method. However when I add in the additional test "should get data and has 1 recordSet" I get a single result (LineItemsHasNextFalse) no matter what I do. I should also mention the stub gets injected via awilix as a singleton. Am I wiring the stub up incorrectly? Is it not possible to change the results using onCall after you have set the returns value?

```
let stub = {
    getRefund: sandbox.stub(),
    getRefunds: sandbox.stub(),
    getRefundItems: sandbox.stub(),
    getRefundTransactions: sandbox.stub()
};

var sandbox = require('sinon').createSandbox();

describe('#refunds', function() {
   
    beforeEach(function () {
         sandbox.spy(logger)
     })
 
     afterEach(function () {
         // completely restore all fakes created through the sandbox
         sandbox.restore();
     })

     context('getRefundItems', function() {

        it('should get data and has 1 recordSet', test(async function() {
            stub.getRefundItems.returns(LineItemsHasNextFalse)
            
            let resp = await refunds.getRefundItems({"gid":"shjdjs"})

            expect(resp).to.deep.equal(LineItemsHasNextFalse.data.refund.refundLineItems.edges)
        }))

        it('should get data and has multiple recordSets', test(async function() {
            let correctResp = new Array()
            correctResp.push(...LineItemsHasNextTrue.data.refund.refundLineItems.edges)
            correctResp.push(...LineItemsHasNextFalse.data.refund.refundLineItems.edges)

            stub.getRefundItems.onCall(0).returns(LineItemsHasNextTrue)
            stub.getRefundItems.onCall(1).returns(LineItemsHasNextFalse)

            let resp = await refunds.getRefundItems({"gid":"shjdjs"})

            console.log(resp)
            expect(resp).to.deep.equal(correctResp)
        }))
    })
})

async getRefundItems(msgObj)
    {
        let hasNext = false
        let items = []
        let count = 0
        do
        {
            let response = await stub.getRefundItems(msgObj)
            if(response.data.refund != null)
            {
                items.push(...response.data.refund.refundLineItems.edges)
                if(response.data.refund.refundLineItems.pageInfo.hasNextPage)
                {
                    let cursor = response.data.refund.refundLineItems.edges[0].cursor
                    msgObj.after = cursor
                    hasNext = true
                }
                else
                {
                    hasNext=false
                }
            }
        }
        while(hasNext)
        return items
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, completed code under test

Comment: @slideshowp2 I have added the minimal version of the method under test